# gzipstream for forward only stream over sockets

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sockets, xmpp, gzip

I am developing an application on windows phone 7.I need to compress/uncompress my data for sending it over tcp sockets.

But I have not been able to find any gzip compressor for forward only stream over tcp sockets.

please help.

Comment: Indeed, `GZipStream` doesn't seem to be present on WP7 - have you tried things like SharpZipLib?

Comment: Sharpziplib does not work for tcp sockets stream

Comment: even the gzip part? why not? what happens? a Stream is a Stream is a Stream...#

Comment: @MarcGravell actually I am using tcp sockets for xmpp.So my data is in the form of packets.From the server end gzip encoding is done.And my client receives data from data in chunks.

Comment: SharpZipLib works fine for me on WP7. I also compress and decompress socket data.

Comment: @Alex can you please elaborate how do you use sharpziplib for tcp sockets.I am using tcp sockets for xmpp.

Answer (score 0):

I created a stripped down version of DotNetZip for this purpose, called DotNetZipLiteWP7. It's available via git here:

https://bitbucket.org/jnewc/dotnetziplitewp7

(Also, I prefer DotNetZip to SharpZipLib as the license is more straight-forward for use in commercial apps).